# Trouble connecting to Cloud SQL in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect to a database on Cloud SQL, but I keep getting the same error. Not sure what it is, and tried several approaches.

Input:

```
import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                             user='',
                             password='XXXX',
                             db='cmcsql')
```

output:

```
C:\Users\Ejer\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\python.exe C:/Users/Ejer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/CloudSQL_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ejer\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 569, in connect
    sock = socket.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Ejer\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Ejer\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Der kunne ikke oprettes forbindelse, fordi destinationscomputeren aktivt nægtede det

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ejer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/CloudSQL_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
  File "C:\Users\Ejer\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pymysql\__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ejer\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 327, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Ejer\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 619, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([WinError 10061] Der kunne ikke oprettes forbindelse, fordi destinationscomputeren aktivt nægtede det)")

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: what are you trying to connect to your cloud sql? App Engine, Compute Engine, on prem machine... How do you want to connect? Using public Ip, Private Ip, Cloud Sql Proxy? provide more context so we can give you clear guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using `127.0.0.1` to connect to cloud sql instance.

`127.0.0.1` is (in most cases) for localhost connection (when you run the db server locally on the same machine as where the client is). Instead you should be using the ip address given to your cloud sql instance. You can find it on the `overview` tab of the sql instance under `Connect to this instance`.

You should also create your user on the `users` tab and then use it in your code.

Don't forget about authentication, check out `connections` tab and read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-overview#authentication_options)

Making sure that you have proper ip, user, existing db and connecting from authorized network should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

PyMysql connects to port 3306 by default, if your process is running on a different port it won't be able to connect.

Apart from the host, user, password parameters you also have to provide the port on which the sql process is running.

Comment: open your mysql shell and use this command, $mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';

Comment: Thank you for the help, but when I type this in the cloud shell, nothing happens

Comment: shouldn't you be using the gcloud IP on which the mysql server is running instead of 127.0.0.1 then?

Comment: I tried this, but still get the same error.